# "prefs:root=CASTLE" not working to open iCloud Settings in IOS10?

Tags: swift3, settings, icloud, ios10, openurl

In my app I have an alert view that has an option to open the iCloud section of the IOS Settings app. This previously worked on IOS8/9 (Swift 2):

```
let settingsCloudKitUrl = URL(string:"prefs:root=CASTLE")
if let url = settingsCloudKitUrl {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

In IOS10 (Swift 3) it isn't working anymore, because openURL() has been deprecated. I changed my code to the following:

```
let settingsCloudKitUrl = URL(string:"prefs:root=CASTLE")
if let url = settingsCloudKitUrl {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

But the above code is not working for IOS10. UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) returns false. What do I have to change to get this working again in IOS10?

Comment: `prefs:` will NOT work since iOS 10. use `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`

Comment: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString will open the section of my app in the IOS Settings app. That's is not what I want. I need the iCloud section to open in the Settings app.

Comment: prefs was an private API...Apple recommends you to use UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString ....to open settings of your app

Comment: Again: I do not want to open the settings of my own app! I want to open the iCloud Settings section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 10 onwards  change `prefs:root=CASTLE` to `App-Prefs:root=CASTLE` and this will work fine

```
let settingsCloudKitUrl = URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=CASTLE")
if let url = settingsCloudKitUrl {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Urls like `App-Prefs:root` are prohibited in App Store and using it causing app rejection.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS!!! APPLE WILL REJECT YOU. Sorry for the caps here but we just got rejected for this